# Erro com o PREDICT no Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning

Eu comecei recentemente a aprender um pouco sobre Machine Learning e classificação, através de um curso na Alura. Bem, eu tentei realizar o primeiro exercício, mas não consegui devido a um erro que não sei dizer o que é. Segue abaixo o código que tenho e o Erro apresentado.

Obs.: Fui tentar rodar o código novamente e agora não reconhece o pacote SKLEARN que tentei importar no arquivo do python.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

pig1 = [1, 1, 0]
pig2 = [1, 1, 0]
pig3 = [1, 1, 0]
dog1 = [1, 1, 1]
dog2 = [0, 1, 1]
dog3 = [1, 0, 1]

dados = [pig1, pig2, pig3, dog1, dog2, dog3]

marcacoes = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]

misterioso = [1, 1, 1] 

modelo = MultinomialNB()

modelo.fit(dados, marcacoes)
print (modelo.predict(misterioso))
```

E aqui foi o que o terminal devolveu:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classificacao.py", line 19, in <module>
    print (modelo.predict(misterioso))
  File "/Users/josecarlosferreira/machinelearning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 66, in predict
    jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
  File "/Users/josecarlosferreira/machinelearning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 724, in _joint_log_likelihood
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/Users/josecarlosferreira/machinelearning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 441, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1 1 1].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Estou a quase 4 dias procurando resolver esse problema e nada de conseguir. Se alguém puder me ajudar para eu seguir com meus estudos.

Comment: a lista misterioso precisa ser 2d, tente fazer misterioso = [[1, 1, 1]]

Comment: Leia com cuidado os erros, no seu caso a resposta está no erro:
"...
print (modelo.predict(misterioso))
...
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead"

Ou seja, você está passando o array 'misterioso' com 1 dimensão e precisa ter 2 dimensões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como descrito pelos comentários, basta utilizar um array de duas dimensões:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

pig1 = [1, 1, 0]
pig2 = [1, 1, 0]
pig3 = [1, 1, 0]
dog1 = [1, 1, 1]
dog2 = [0, 1, 1]
dog3 = [1, 0, 1]

dados = [pig1, pig2, pig3, dog1, dog2, dog3]

marcacoes = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]

misterioso = [
    [1, 1, 1]
]

modelo = MultinomialNB()

modelo.fit(dados, marcacoes)
print (modelo.predict(misterioso))
```

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1